# How to determine this integral interval after a complicated substitution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Calculate:
$$I=\iint\limits_{D}\frac{\text{d}x\text{d}y}{xy(\ln^2x+\ln^2y)}\\
 \quad\text{$D$ is an area enclosed by the two functions} \color{violet}{\text{ in the first quadrant}}:\\
D:(\text{enclosed by})\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=1\\
x+y=1
\end{cases}
$$

---

Here's my approach:
Integration by substitution:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=e^{r\cos\theta} \\
y=e^{r\sin\theta}
\end{cases} \Rightarrow\text{det}\mathbf{J}=\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}=re^{r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}
$$

The boundary $D$ after substitution:
$$
\Delta:(\text{enclosed by})\begin{cases}
e^{2r\cos\theta}+e^{2r\sin\theta}=1\\
e^{r\cos\theta}+e^{r\sin\theta}=1
\end{cases}
$$
Now:
$$I=\iint\limits_{\Delta}\frac{\text{d}r\text{d}\theta}{r}=?$$
And I don't know how to continue because of the implicit equations above.

Comment: The final result seems to be $\;\cfrac{\pi\,\ln2}2\;$ , and the limits could be $\;\;0\le\theta\le\cfrac\pi2\;,\;\;\cfrac1{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}\le r\le 1\;$ ...but this renders an impossible (for me, at least) integral there...

Comment: @DonAntonio Your result is correct but, in order to satisfy this equation:$e^{r\cos\theta}+e^{r\sin\theta}=1$, this $\cos\theta$  and  $\sin\theta$ must be negative ($r>0$), so $ \theta $ should be in the third quadrant.

Comment: Perhaps so, but the problem gives that we're in the first quadrant...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to find the exact interval after the complicated substitution.

The boundary $D$ after substitution:
$$
\Delta:(\text{enclosed by})\begin{cases}
(1):\quad e^{r\cos\theta}+e^{r\sin\theta}=1 \label{eq1} \\
(2):\quad e^{2r\cos\theta}+e^{2r\sin\theta}=1 
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to find that $\theta \in [\pi,3\pi/2]$.

Now let the function determined by the equation (1) be $r=r(\theta)$.

Hence the equation (2) determines:$r = r(\theta)/2$ and:

$$
I=\iint\limits_{\Delta}\frac{\text{d}r\text{d}\theta}{r}=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\text{d}\theta\int_{r(\theta)/2}^{r(\theta)}\frac{\text{d}r}{r}=\frac{\pi\ln2}{2}
$$